# Re-combine different axes to make new figure in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I am curious that whether this is possible in matplotlib:

I first create some figures, with subplots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig1, axs1 = plt.subplots(2, 2)
fig2, axs2 = plt.subplots(2, 2)
```

And then, could I recombine them, so fig3 is composed of the first row in fig1 (i.e., axs1[0, 0] and axs1[0, 1]) and second row in fig2 (i.e., axs2[1, 0] and axs2[1, 1])?

Currently, all I could do is to re-plot them. I am curious about whether there is a way that I can just move axes around and re-combine them to make new figures. Thanks!

-Shawn

Comment: I am not aware of any features in matplotlib allowing it. As far I understand matplotlib, it delegates the creation of plot windows to a UI-toolkit (qt, gtk, ...). So combining existing windows has to be done in them - maybe by embedding maplotlib figures in other toolkit windows.